# How to filter array of objects by element property values using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I like to filter json files using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
jq . some.json
```

Given the json containing an array of objects:

```
{
  "theList": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Horst"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Fritz"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Walter"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Gerhart"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Harmut"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter that list to only show the elements with id having the value 2 and 4, so the expected output is:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Fritz"
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Gerhart"
}
```

How do I filter the json using jq? I have played around with select and map, yet didn't got any of those to work, e.g.:

```
$ jq '.theList[] | select(.id == 2) or select(.id == 4)' array.json
true
```

Comment: **Everyone please note:** The question is about [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/#), not jQuery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder YMMD ^^ And I clarified in the question :D

Answer (score 156, accepted):

**From the docs:**

> ```
> jq '.[] | select(.id == "second")'
> ```
>
> **Input** `[{"id": "first", "val": 1}, {"id": "second", "val": 2}]`
>
> **Output** `{"id": "second", "val": 2}`

I think you can do something like this:

```
jq '.theList[] | select(.id == 2 or .id == 4)' array.json
```

Comment: `jq '.theList[] | select(.id == 2) or select(.id == 4)' array.json` yields in: `true` o.O

Comment: It's returning the evaluation of both clauses, try this:
`jq '.theList[] | select(.id == 2 or .id == 4)'`

Comment: `jq '.theList[] | select(.id == 2 or .id == 4)' array.json` did the trick, you may update your answer :)

Answer (score 24):

You could use `select` within `map`.

```
.theList | map(select(.id == (2, 4)))
```

Or more compact:

```
[ .theList[] | select(.id == (2, 4)) ]
```

Though written that way is a little inefficient since the expression is duplicated for every value being compared. It'll be more efficient and possibly more readable written this way:

```
[ .theList[] | select(any(2, 4; . == .id)) ]
```

Comment: Clever use of [if behavior when condition returns multiple results](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/docs/content/3.manual/manual.yml#L2033-L2035)!

Answer (score 10):

Using `select(.id == (2, 4))` here is generally inefficient (see below).

If your jq has `IN/1`, then it can be used to achieve a more efficient solution:

```
.theList[] | select( .id | IN(2,3))
```

If your jq does not have `IN/1`, then you can define it as follows:

```
def IN(s): first(select(s == .)) // false;
```

**Efficiency**

One way to see the inefficiency is to use `debug`.  The following expression, for example, results in 10 calls to `debug`, whereas only 9 checks for equality are actually needed:

```
.theList[] | select( (.id == (2,3)) | debug )

["DEBUG:",false]
["DEBUG:",false]
["DEBUG:",true]
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Fritz"
}
["DEBUG:",false]
["DEBUG:",false]
["DEBUG:",true]
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Walter"
}
["DEBUG:",false]
["DEBUG:",false]
["DEBUG:",false]
["DEBUG:",false]
```

**index/1**

In principle, using `index/1` should be efficient, but as of this writing (October 2017), its implementation, though fast (it is written in C), is inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [indices](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#indices(s)):

```
.theList | [ .[map(.id)|indices(2,4)[]] ]
```