# How can I loop through my json with Bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json file which looks like this:

```
{
  "version": {
    "Generated": "@logon",
    "Value": "Unknown",
    "LastRun": "Never"
  },
  "hostname": {
    "Generated": "@logon",
    "Value": "Unknown",
    "LastRun": "Never"
  },
  "updates": {
    "Generated": "@boot",
    "Value": "Unknown",
    "LastRun": "Never"
  }
}
```

How can I loop through each element in the json file in Bash which has as "Generated" value "@logon"? I guess I should use jq, but I didn't manage to find the right filter.

Comment: Hey I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38122029/7111561) should be what you need

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use bash to loop through the JSON objects satisfying the condition, consider:

```
while read -r val ; do
    echo "${val}"
done < <(jq -rc '.[] | select(.Generated == "@logon")' file.json)
```

Output:

```
{"Generated":"@logon","Value":"Unknown","LastRun":"Never"}
{"Generated":"@logon","Value":"Unknown","LastRun":"Never"}
```

The -c option is needed if this approach to looping in bash is adopted.

Of course it would be preferable to do as much processing of JSON objects within jq as possible.

If you want to loop through the top-level key-value pairs, then you will probably want to use `to_entries` or maybe `with_entries`.  For example, to print the keys of objects with .Generated == "@logon":

```
$ jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.value.Generated == "@logon") | .key' input.json
version
hostname
```

Notice - no bash loop needed!

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
jq -r '.[].Generated' file.json | while read -r val ; do
    do_something "${val}"
done
```

Comment: I think he also wants to differentiate `@logon` and `@boot` values, so an additional comparison would suffice.

Comment: Looks you are right. I'm waiting for clarification on what `jq` should print then.