# In jq, can you get objects back in a list, so you can index them?

Tags: jq

So, say I have this JSON...

```
[
  {
    "a": "1",
    "blah": "true"
  },
  {
    "b": "2",
    "blah": "false"
  },
  {
    "c": "3",
    "blah": "true"
  }
]
```

...and then use jq to select certain entries...

```
jq '.[] | select(.blah=="true)'
```

I get this...

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "blah": "true"
}
{
  "c": "3",
  "blah": "true"
}
```

But I *want* it to look like...

```
[
  {
    "a": "1",
    "blah": "true"
  }
  {
    "c": "3",
    "blah": "true"
  }
]
```

...this, so that I can use indexing to get certain of these entries. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter array of objects by element property values using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121740/how-to-filter-array-of-objects-by-element-property-values-using-jq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply indicate you want the result in a list by wrapping the expression with [];

```
> cat test.json | jq '[.[] | select(.blah=="true")]'

[
  {
    "a": "1",
    "blah": "true"
  },
  {
    "c": "3",
    "blah": "true"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` to iterate over the array

```bash
jq 'map(select(.blah == "true"))'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using param -s:

```
jq  '.[]|select(.blah=="true")' | jq -s '.'
```