# Filtering Json output with jq or grep

Tags: json, jq

I have a Json with this kind of records and I want to filter it using jq or grep to get an output with only the full records where "__pod_controller_name" its "podIwant"

```
{
  "endpoint": "http://10.225.25.33:8080/metrics",
  "properties": {
    "__pod_name": "pod1",
    "__pod_controller_name": "podIwant"
  }
}
{
  "endpoint": "http://10.225.10.21:8080/metrics",
  "properties": {
    "__pod_name": "pod2",
    "__pod_controller_name": "podIdontwant"
  }
}
{
  "endpoint": "http://10.225.33.52:8080/metrics",
  "properties": {
    "__pod_name": "pod3",
    "__pod_controller_name": "podIwant"
  }
}
```

I've been trying with a lot of jq and map commands but I could not.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter array of objects by element property values using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121740/how-to-filter-array-of-objects-by-element-property-values-using-jq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For structured data like JSON, use appropriate tools like jq, not grep. With jq, you can filter using `select`. It takes some filter, and if it evaluates to `true` its input is passed on.

```bash
jq 'select(.properties.__pod_controller_name == "podIwant")' input.json
```

If you want the query string to be dynamic (adjustable from the calling environment), use the `--arg` flag to bind it to a variable:

```bash
jq --arg name 'podIwant' 'select(.properties.__pod_controller_name == $name)' input.json
```

Output:

```json
{
  "endpoint": "http://10.225.25.33:8080/metrics",
  "properties": {
    "__pod_name": "pod1",
    "__pod_controller_name": "podIwant"
  }
}
{
  "endpoint": "http://10.225.33.52:8080/metrics",
  "properties": {
    "__pod_name": "pod3",
    "__pod_controller_name": "podIwant"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4y2g6rL7ULG)

Comment: THANKS a lot. How could be if i'm looking to output the records that does not match perfectly with the value but contains the string i want? If "__pod_controller_name" is "12.podIwant.1.3" and the other one I want is "34.podIwant.2.3". I cannot make it work using contain instead of == :/

Comment: @SugusTHC You can use `contains` ([manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#contains(element))) for a partial matching or `test` ([manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#test(val),test(regex;flags))) for a full regex matching. [Here](https://jqplay.org/s/bwTNp-frZk3) is a demo how to use `contains` on the strings given.